Unable to map the fields of Class from two classes in mapstruct
@Mapping(source = "key.locationType", target = "basicLocation.locationTypeCode")
@Mapping(source = "detail.locationName", target = "basicLocation.locationName")
LocationRequest toRequest(CachedLocationKey key, CachedLocationDetail detail);

I am trying to map the object basicLocation in LocationRequest.  locationType comes from key and locationName comes from detail.
If I write both the mappings , there comes the below error :
@Mapping(source = "key.locationType", target = "basicLocation.locationTypeCode")     
@Mapping(source = "detail.locationName", target = "basicLocation.locationName")

error:

java: No read accessor found for property "basicLocation" in target type.

On using either one of the mappings, it works fine.
@Mapping(source = "key.locationType", target = "basicLocation.locationTypeCode")

or
@Mapping(source = "detail.locationName", target = "basicLocation.locationName")

but I need to map both the fields to the basicLocation object. am I missing something here ?

please share how your LocationRequest looks like. Btw, did you see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287617/cannot-map-nested-data-with-mapstruct?
